# Tabular data calculation - summing in middle of table

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, view

Consider a simple query:

`SELECT id, date, hours FROM employees where id=10`

And the following result set:

```
id | date     | hours
---------------------
1   4-19-2012   4
1   4-19-2012   2.5
1   4-19-2012   1
1   4-20-2012   2
1   4-20-2012   3
```

I'm showing a typical HTML table output of the result set but I'd like to display a daily summation on a row underneath of that days results.

```
+--------------------------------------+
| David | 4-19-2012 | 4                |
|       | 4-19-2012 | 2.5              |
|       | 4-19-2012 | 1                |
|--------------------------------------|
| TOTAL ............  7.5              |
|--------------------------------------|
| David | 4-20-2012 | 2                |
|       | 4-20-2012 | 1                |
|--------------------------------------|
| TOTAL ............ 3                 |
|--------------------------------------|
| GRAND TOTAL ..........10.5           |
+--------------------------------------+
```

What are some of the best ways to handle that? There are many options. Subquerying... putting PHP code in my view... surely there is a bettery way.

Comment: Use [`GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) ?

Comment: Snaps. That'll work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Upgraded to an answer*

In MySQL, you can add extra summary rows in a table that is grouped with `GROUP BY` by using the [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier:

> The `GROUP BY` clause permits a `WITH ROLLUP` modifier that causes extra rows to be added to the summary output. These rows represent higher-level (or super-aggregate) summary operations. `ROLLUP` thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. It can be used, for example, to provide support for OLAP (Online Analytical Processing) operations.

With your query, you could do:

```sql
SELECT id, date, SUM(hours) AS totalhours
FROM employees
WHERE id = 10
GROUP BY id, date, hours WITH ROLLUP
```